# SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected ";" for .css files using Prettier

Tags: typescript, eslint, prettier

I am trying to use Prettier with eslint and TypeScript. When I am running `npm run prettier -- --list-different` all of my css files are getting the error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected ";"`. I am thinking it is an issue with the way I have my parsing set up, but cannot seem to get it to work. This is my current setup.

.eslintrc

```
{
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2018,
    "sourceType":  "module",
    "ecmaFeatures":  {
      "jsx":  true
    }
  },
  "extends": [
      "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
      "plugin:react/recommended",
      "prettier/@typescript-eslint",
      "plugin:prettier/recommended"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "no-console": "warn",
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": ["warn", {"allowExpressions": true}]
  },
  "settings": {
      "react" : {
        "createClass": "createReactClass",
        "pragma": "React",
        "version":  "detect"
      }
  },
  "env": {
    "browser": true
  }
}
```

.prettierrc

```
{
  "arrowParens": "avoid",
  "bracketSpacing": true,
  "htmlWhitespaceSensitivity": "css",
  "insertPragma": false,
  "jsxBracketSameLine": false,
  "jsxSingleQuote": false,
    "parser": "babel",
    "printWidth": 120,
    "proseWrap": "always",
    "requirePragma": false,
    "semi": true,
    "singleQuote": true,
    "tabWidth": 2,
    "trailingComma": "none",
    "useTabs": false        
}
```

css file

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

package.json (just in case)

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.8",
    "react-scripts-ts": "3.1.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "typescript": "^3.4.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint": "eslint --ext js,jsx,ts,tsx --max-warnings 0 -f codeframe --cache --color src",
    "format": "npm run prettier -- --write",
    "prettier": "prettier \"**/*.+(js|jsx|json|yml|yaml|css|less|scss|ts|tsx|md|graphql|mdx)\"",
    "validate": "npm run lint && npm run prettier -- --list-different && tsc",
    "precommit": "lint-staged && tsc",
    "typecheck": "tsc"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/classnames": "^2.2.7",
    "@types/enzyme": "^3.9.1",
    "@types/enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.0.5",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.11",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.123",
    "@types/node": "^11.13.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.8.13",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.8.3",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.0.6",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^1.6.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^1.6.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.9.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.12.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^4.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.12.4",
    "prettier": "^1.16.4",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.6.2",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

I have tried adding overrides to the `.prettierrc` and `.eslintrc` files like this but it did not work.

```
"overrides": [{
    "files": "*.css",
    "options": {
        "parser": "babel"
     }
}]
```

Comment: `.eslintignore` file was helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64931551/470749

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Turns out I needed to add the `overrides` to the `.prettierrc` file with the parser set to css. I was using the wrong parser, trying things like `postcss-scss` instead. It would look like this.

```
"overrides": [
  {
    "files": "*.css",
    "options": {
      "parser": "css"
    }
  }
]
```

Documentation is here: https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#parser

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I needed.