# How do I fix typescript compiler errors on css files?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, css-modules

**I'm trying to create a React project with typescript using webpack. But I can't manage to get CSS modules working. I keep getting this error when trying to import the CSS files in typescript:**

```
ERROR in src/components/Button.module.css:1:0
[unknown]: Parsing error: Declaration or statement expected.
  > 1 | .myButton {
    2 |         box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px -1px #1c1b18;
    3 |         background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #eae0c2 5%, #ccc2a6 100%);
    4 |         background-color:#eae0c2;
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

To me this looks like webpack is expecting the css file to contain valid typescript but I don't know for sure. I tried looking around and while a lot of people seem to be struggeling with using typescript and CSS modules together I couldn't find anyone with a similar issue.

I imported the CSS file like this:
Button.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import "./Button.module.css";

export class Button extends React.Component{
...
}
```

And this is the CSS file that I'm trying to import.
Button.module.css:

```
.myButton {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px -1px #1c1b18;
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #eae0c2 5%, #ccc2a6 100%);
    background-color:#eae0c2;
    border-radius:22px;
    border:4px solid #706752;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#505739;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:11px 22px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #ffffff;
}
.myButton:hover {
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #ccc2a6 5%, #eae0c2 100%);
    background-color:#ccc2a6;
}
.myButton:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
```

The generated Button.module.css.d.ts

```
// This file is automatically generated.
// Please do not change this file!
interface CssExports {

}
export const cssExports: CssExports;
export default cssExports;
```

I also have a type declaration for css modules called styles.d.ts

```
declare module "*.module.css" {
    const classes: { [key: string]: string };
    export default classes;
}
```

While Webpack does seem to generate some typings for the css module it looks weirdly empty to me. I think I doing something wrong with the css-modules-typescript-loader, I tried with a bunch of the avaliable plugins but keep running into the same error reguardless.

Here is what I configured in my webpack.config.ts:

```
import webpack from "webpack";

const config: webpack.Configuration = {
  entry: "./src/index.tsx",
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js", ".css"],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.module.css$/,
        use: [
          "css-modules-typescript-loader",
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: true,
              sourceMap: true,
            }
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: [
              "@babel/preset-env",
              "@babel/preset-react",
              "@babel/preset-typescript",
            ],
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "target": "ES5",
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "typescript-plugin-css-modules"
      }
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I had same issue. In my case, it was not the webpack's problem. It was the problem of typescript-eslint. I solved the problem by adding "*.css" in .eslintignore file.

Comment: You can also solve by adding `"ignorePatterns": ["**/*.css"],` to your `.eslintrc.js` file.

Answer (score 5):

### Add this line to .eslintrc.json

```
  {
    ...
    "ignorePatterns": ["**/*.css","**/*.scss"]
  }
```

### .eslintrc.js

```
module.exports = {
    ...
    ignorePatterns: ["**/*.css", "**/*.scss"],
};
```